# Javascript Content in Imacros doesn't work

Tags: javascript

javascript CONTENT in Imacros doesn't work properly

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=TYPE:file&&NAME:pic CONTENT=**C:\Users\PC\Desktop\pics\boys\1.jpg** » this works

```
    //code
    macro += "WAIT SECONDS=1 \n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=TYPE:file&&NAME:pic CONTENT=C:\Users\PC\Desktop\pics\boys\1.jpg \n";
    //more macrocode
```

and the file input shows the file like this "CUsersPcDesktoppicsboys1.jpg"

Does anyone know whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=TYPE:file&&NAME:pic CONTENT=C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\pics\\boys\\1.jpg" + "\n";
```

It goes like this.